# Recursion formula in dynamic programming

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

Where l_1 = 1, l_2 = 4, l_3 = 5 are blocks with different length and I need to make one big block with the length of l = 8 using the  formula.

Can someone explain me the following formula:

[image]

The formula is in LaTeX, with array L = [l + 1]

Sorry about the formatting, but I can`t upload images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be about finding what is the minimum number of blocks needed to make a bigger block. Also, there seems to be no restriction on the number of individual blocks available.

Assuming you have blocks of n different lengths. `l1, l2 .. ln`. What is the minimum number of blocks you can use to make one big block of length `k`?

The idea behind the recursive formula is that you can make a block of length `i` by adding one block of length `l1` to a hypothetical big block of length `i-l1` that you might already have made using the minimum number of blocks (because that is what your `L` array holds. For any index `j`, it holds the minimum number of blocks needed to make a block of size `j`). Say the `i-l1` block was built using 4 blocks. Using those 4 blocks and 1 more block of size `l1`, you created a block of size `i` using 5 blocks.

But now, say a block of size `i-l2` was made only using 3 blocks. Then you could easily add another block of size `l2` to this block of size `i-l2` and make a block of size `i` using only 4 blocks!

That is the idea behind iterating over all possible block lengths and choosing the minimum of them all (mentioned in the third line of your latex image).

Hope that helps.